# How to remove object from observableArrayList() based on property of said object?

Tags: java

I have 2 observableArrayLists that consist of ***Appointment*** and ***Customer*** objects that I display inside the application window via 2 tableViews. They are populated from SQL database.

I wrote ***deleteCustomer*** method that processes SQL operations and at the end calls following method to remove the  object from the list:

```
            MainScreenController.customerDisplayList.remove(deletedCustomer);
```

Right before the deletion of the customer I also execute following code to remove all appointments related to deleted customer since appointment table contains a column with foreign key that is pointed to primary key in customer table:

```
    public static void deleteAppointments(int customerId) throws Exception {
    DatabaseConnection.makeConnection();
    String sqlStatement = "DELETE FROM appointment WHERE customerId = '" + customerId + "'";
    Query.makeQuery(sqlStatement);
    DatabaseConnection.closeConnection();
}
```

Now my question is how do I remove Appointments that are contained in observableArrayList based on customerId property that is stored within Appointment object?

Thank you all for your time and patience!

Answer (score 0):

After some more research I found that Appointments can be removed from the ArrayList by following code:

```
            MainScreenController.appointmentDisplayList.removeIf(Appointment -> Appointment.getCustomerId() == deletedCustomer.getCustomerId());
```

Comment: `Appointment -> Appointment.getCustomerId()`. The capitalizaton of `appointment` in both cases is a terrible coding practice in `Java`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Will definitely keep that in mind. I just started about 2 month ago!

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html